# Bootstrap table overflow issue

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table inside an accordion, the problem is that the table goes over the div in width, I want to make the table smaller, and prevent the overflow.

If I add the 'table-responsive' class, it only becomes scrollable, but I can't alter the size of the cells.

```css
.timetable-cell {
    width: 1rem ;
}
.reserved-cell {
    width: 1rem ;
    background-color: #cd5c5c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card-body">
  <table id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable" border="1" class="table">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2&quot;">08:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">09:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">10:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">11:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">12:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">13:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">14:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">15:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">16:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">17:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">18:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">19:00</th>
      <th colspan="2">20:00</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_day_MON">MON</th>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_1" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_2" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_3" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_4" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_5" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_6" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_7" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_8" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_9" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_10" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_11" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_12" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_13" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_14" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_15" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_16" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_17" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_18" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_19" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_20" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_21" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_22" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_23" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_24" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_25" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_1_26" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_day_TUE">TUE</th>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_1" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_2" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_3" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_4" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_5" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_6" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_7" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_8" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_9" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_10" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_11" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_12" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_13" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_14" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_15" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_16" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_17" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_18" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_19" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_20" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_21" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_22" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_23" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_24" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_25" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_2_26" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_day_WED">WED</th>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_1" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_2" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_3" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_4" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_5" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_6" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_7" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_8" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_9" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_10" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_11" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_12" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_13" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_14" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_15" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_16" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_17" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_18" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_19" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_20" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_21" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_22" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_23" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_24" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_25" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_3_26" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_day_THU">THU</th>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_1" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_2" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_3" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_4" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_5" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_6" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_7" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_8" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_9" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_10" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_11" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_12" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_13" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_14" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_15" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_16" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_17" class="reserved-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_18" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_19" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_20" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_21" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_22" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_23" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_24" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_25" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_4_26" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_day_FRI">FRI</th>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_1" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_2" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_3" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_4" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_5" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_6" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_7" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_8" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_9" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_10" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_11" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_12" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_13" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_14" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_15" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_16" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_17" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_18" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_19" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_20" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_21" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_22" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_23" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_24" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_25" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_5_26" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_day_SAT">SAT</th>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_1" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_2" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_3" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_4" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_5" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_6" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_7" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_8" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_9" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_10" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_11" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_12" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_13" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_14" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_15" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_16" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_17" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_18" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_19" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_20" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_21" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_22" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_23" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_24" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_25" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
      <td id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable_6_26" class="timetable-cell" style="width: 1rem"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My desire is that the table stays contained inside its parent without the overflow.

Comment: Your `div` doesn't have any restrictions or styling? So it will take the full width and hence the table as well.If you put something like 50% on the div it will automatically reduce table cell size

Comment: Reduce the font size and also reduce the cell padding.

Comment: cell padding didn't have any effect, where as font size affected the height not the width of the cell. 50% on div had no effect

Comment: If you add 'table-sm' class to 'table''s div is it enough? Do you want more smaller?

Comment: @ReSedano tried it, didnt work 

Comment: Sorry, to table not to div '<table id="BENG_2_Fall_timetable" border="1" class="table table-sm">'. This is the documentation's link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/

Comment: @ReSedano yes that’s what i did, i’ll read the documentation again maybe i missed something

Comment: @jaafar Nasrallah https://jsfiddle.net/g4r9Lbko/ I see it smaller, without padding.

Comment: @ReSedano I think there might be some other css interfering in here, I’ll do a thorough check, and once I find it i’ll post the answer here. Thanks though

Comment: @jaafar Nasrallah Maybe you're right. I only copy and past your code and add that class. Good luck to your check! ;)